# null Firestore whit reactive form

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following reactive form:

```
this.forma = fb.group ({
  valorPropiedad: [ 100000, Validators.required ],
  nombre: [ '', Validators.required ],
  email : [ '', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
  celular: [ '',  [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(9)] ],
  acepta : [ false, Validators.requiredTrue ],
  fecha: [ firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() ],
  estado: [ false ],
});
```

My button is disabled by default until the required fields have been validated.

My html form:

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="agregarDomiciliario()" novalidate>

        <div class="row">

          <mat-form-field class="col-md-12">
            <input matInput placeholder="Valor de la vivienda (US$ - Dólares americanos)" type="number" formControlName="valorPropiedad">
            <span class="mr-2" matPrefix>US$ </span>
            <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['valorPropiedad'].invalid">{{ errorValorPropiedad() }}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Ingresa tu email" type="email" formControlName="email">
          <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['email'].invalid">{{ errorEmail() }}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="row">
          <mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
            <input matInput placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" type="text" formControlName="nombre">
            <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['nombre'].invalid">{{ errorNombre() }}</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field class="col-md-6">
            <input matInput #celular  maxlength="9" placeholder="Ingresa tu celular" type="text" formControlName="celular">
            <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['celular'].invalid">{{ errorCelular() }}</mat-error>
            <mat-hint align="end">{{celular.value.length}} / 9</mat-hint>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

        <mat-checkbox class="small" formControlName="acepta">Acepto los <a [routerLink] (click)="openDialog()">términos y condiciones</a></mat-checkbox>

        <div class="mt-3">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block shadow" [disabled]="!forma.valid">Quiero más información <i class="fas fa-arrow-right ml-2"></i></button>
        </div>  
      </form>
```

component.ts

```
agregarDomiciliario() {
this.fs.addDomiciliario(this.forma.value);
console.log(this.forma.value);
this.form.resetForm({ 
  fecha: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  estado: false
});

this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action, {
  duration: 5000,
});
}
```

service.ts

```
addDomiciliario(domiciliario){
this.afs.collection('domiciliarios').add(domiciliario);
}
```

Everything is working correctly I did several tests all OK, but it turns out that after several days I just received a firestore document with `null` values I do not understand how, if the formulator does not allow you to send if the form is not validated.

[image]

Can someone explain to me what may be happening?

Comment: Can you add the `agregarDomiciliario()` function code?

Comment: I just edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

When you reset an reactive form, all values are set to null. 
So the result you see is what I would expect. But the problem is that you don't take into consideration the asynchronous nature, of the operation to firestore.

To get the result you are looking for, you should refactor to this:

```
async agregarDomiciliario() {
  await this.fs.addDomiciliario(this.forma.value);
  // Wait for firestore, before resetting the form
  this.form.resetForm({ 
    fecha: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    estado: false
  });
  // Show the snackbar
  this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action, {
    duration: 5000,
  });
}

addDomiciliario(domiciliario){
  return this.afs.collection('domiciliarios').add(domiciliario);
}
```

To learn more about async await I can recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=568g8hxJJp4&t=59s).

Answer (score 1):

The `add()` method is an asynchronous promise, and you are resetting the form synchronously, so it gets reset before we know for sure if it added the document. Try this:

service.ts:

```
addDomiciliario(domiciliario): Promise<any> {
  return this.afs.collection('domiciliarios').add(domiciliario);
}
```

component.ts:

```
agregarDomiciliario() {
  this.addDomiciliario(this.forma.value).then(() => {
    this.form.resetForm({ 
      fecha: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      estado: false
    });

    this.snackBar.open(this.message, this.action, {
      duration: 5000,
    });
  }, error => console.error('error submitting form:', error));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to make sense. When I added `promise` I got an error so I changed it to` promise <any>`. Now, is there any way to simulate an error to know that this works?

Comment: You could make `databaseURL` in your firebase config an empty string